# Workers constantly rebooting when killed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting a server on 3000 and it always boots two workers. I kill the pids and then new pids pop up.

I've tried lsof, killing pids and even running a server parent killer program.

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.1.6.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[23820] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[23820] * Version 3.9.1 (ruby 2.3.4-p301), codename: Private Caller
[23820] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[23820] * Environment: development
[23820] * Process workers: 2
[23820] * Preloading application
[23820] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
[23820] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[23820] - Worker 0 (pid: 23982) booted, phase: 0
[23820] - Worker 1 (pid: 23983) booted, phase: 0
```

Comment: reduce the number of workers in config

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Do you want to kill the rails puma server?